# Difference between two features in same polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, features, differences

I have a polygon and some features are below another features. If I would have two different polygons I would use the `"Difference"` tool so it would take the overlapping feauters to the "surface".

Does anybody knows a method (if there´s any) on how to do a kind of difference tool but with different features in the same polygon?

Comment: Could you please quickly sketch a picture (printscreen) of what you have currently and how you want to see it? I am a bit lost in what you mean by "difference of different features in the same polygon".

Answer (score 1):

Is creating the magenta polygons where the polygon layer intersects itself what you are trying to do? If so you can use pyqgis and intersect all combinations of polygons:

[image]

```
from itertools import combinations

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Overlaps')[0] #Change to match your data

intersections = []
for poly1, poly2 in combinations(layer.getFeatures(), 2):
    if poly1.geometry().intersects(poly2.geometry()):
        intersections.append(poly1.geometry().intersection(poly2.geometry()))

vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiPolygon?crs={}&index=yes".format(layer.crs().authid()), "intersectionsLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()
for poly in intersections: 
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(poly)
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to achieve two layers:

- First that contains only overlapping features
- Second that includes features with no overlaps

Let's assume there is a polygon layer `"grid"` with its attribute table accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Apply the SAGA's module `"Polygon self-intersection"`

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the following expression `if("ID" LIKE '%|%', 0, 1)` in the Field Calculator.

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** Continue with a `"Split vector layer"` using the `"key"`-field created at the *Step 2*. Application of `"Fix geometries"` on this step may be necessary. And get the output, see image below.

[image: result]

*Note:* Mind that the final output(s) is(are) in `.gpkg`-format.